What amount of egoism is natural, even necessary, even moral?
In his second theorem in the Critique of Practical Reason, Kant states that a rational being's consciousness of the agreeableness of life accompanying his whole existence is happiness, and the principle of making this the supreme determining ground of choice is the principle of self-love. He then devotes Book I of the Analytic of this Critique to arguing that such an empirical ground cannot serve as the basis for moral law.
Self-love sounds egotistic but also natural.  A certain amount seems even necessary.  What is a good amount of self-love and can it be compatibly integrated into a system of ethics?  If so, I assume such an ethic would not comport with Kant's idea of morality?
Would this explain Nietzsche's antipathy towards Kant?
Reference Critique of Practical Reason, 5:22

For "what is a good amount of X" to make sense, you need some value over and above X to pass a judgment on it. Apparently, you are not bound by Kant's idea of morality, so what would that value be? Without it, the answer is whatever amount you want. Indeed, ethical egoism declares unbounded self-interest the ultimate value. Of course, some semblance of caring about others would still follow, because gaining their trust and cooperation may well be in one's self-interest. Sometimes this is called "self-referential altruism".

If suicide, prohibited by  Kant, is the opposite of self love, then self-love is moral, at least to the extent demanded by the universal form,
